# I would like help getting my pagination to work

Tags: pagination

When i click on the any link in the pagination it shows a blank page.
forward and backward works. and the number of published post that show up is off by two on the number. please help.

```
<?php 

$per_page = 5; 

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','wordpress');

 if($connection){
     echo 'connected to the database';
 }

 else {
    echo 'not connected to the database';
 }


?>


<?php
if(isset($_GET['page'])){

$page = $_GET['page'];

} else {

    $page = "";
}

if($page == "" || $page == 1) {

    $page_1 = 0;

} 

else {
    $page_1 = ($page * 5) - 5;
}


?>


<?php
$post_query_count = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts";
$find_count = mysqli_query($connection,$post_query_count);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($find_count);

$count = ceil($count / $per_page);
echo $count;


$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts LIMIT $page_1, 5";
$select_all_posts_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_posts_query)) {
$post_id = $row['ID'];  // is this post_id or ID?
$post_title = $row['post_title']; //
$post_author = $row['post_author']; //
$post_date = $row['post_date']; //
$post_image = $row['post_image']; 
$post_content = substr($row['post_content'],0,400); //
$post_status = $row['post_status']; //

if($post_status == 'published'){ } 


}

?>

<h1><?php echo 'total blog post' . "" . $count ?></h1>


<!-- below is the default wordpress php loop code block --> 



<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>


    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <!--beginning of  title above -->

            <!-- blog Headers below -->
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

        <!--end of  title above -->




            <!-- Featured image -->
            <div class="entry">

            <!-- date posted on and by the author -->
           <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?> 

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

            <div class="blogInsert"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail'); ?></a></div>

                <?php the_content('Continue reading &raquo;'); ?>

            </div><!--end of the blog entry-->



            <!-- beginning of entry is either featured image or the middle piece-->


            <!--begin of the catagorized & comments -->
            <div class="postmetadata">
                <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
                Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | 
                <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>

            </div>
            <!--end of the catagorized & comments -->


        </div><!--end of blogEntry-->

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php next_posts_link('Older Entries'); ?>

<?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries'); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

    <h2>Not Found</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>

        <?php 
        $ourCurrentPage = get_query_var('paged');
        $aboutPosts = new WP_query(array('category_name' => 'about', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $ourCurrentPage )); ?>
<ul class="paging-navigation">

<br>
<br>

<?php


for($i =1; $i <= $count; $i++) {

echo "<li><a href='index.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";

}

?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Jack do I use one  back tick before and after the code to get it to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_GET['paged']` instead of `$_GET['page']`